# python's putpixel() isn't working

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I was working on this school project (I know really basic programming, and python is the only language I know) where I need to change my pixel colour to encode a message in a picture, but PIL's putpixel doesn't seem to be working, here is my code.

P.S.: all my PIL information is self taught and English isn't my main language so if you could talk simplified I'd be grateful

```
from PIL import Image
e=input('file and location?  ')
img=Image.open(e)
pmap=img.load()
imy=img.height
imx=img.width
if int(input('1 for encoding, 2 for decoding   '))==1:
    a=input('Your message?   ')
    for i in range(len(a)):
        r , g , b=img.getpixel((i+10,imy//2))
        img.putpixel((i+10,imy//2),(ord(a[i]),g,b))
    r,g,b=img.getpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2))
    img.putpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2),(999,g,b)) #999 is the stop code in     decoding
else:
    r=u=0
    m=''
    while r!=999:
        r , g , b=img.getpixel((10+u,imy//2))
        m+=chr(r)
        u+=1
    print(m[:len(a)-1])
img.save(e)
```

please bare in mind that I'm not looking to make a visual difference and I've already done debugging.There are also no errors,putpixel is not working for some reason though.
as I said, I'm new to programming, so sorry if it includes stupid mistakes.

Comment: Well, I'd say it's not a bad question being your first one. However, try to explain a little bit more what the error is. If you don't see an error, tell us about what do you get versus what do you expect. Remember, the more effort you put explaining your issues, the easier for the community is to help you.

Comment: well im not getting any errors,the pixels just don't change at all,like the putpixel is doing nothing and I don't think I've done anything wrong

Comment: Ok, try adding some debug lines. To understand what's going on. For example, you could add `print a` below the `a=input('Your message?   ')` statement, and make sure you are actually storing the value you expect. In the same way, add a few more `print` statements.

Comment: You are just modifying some single pixels. Are you sure nothing has changed? You may not "see" it looking at the image.

Comment: I've already done the debugging,everything works fine,the only problem is that in the end of the program,I never reach the pixel in which r=999 so the loop will go on until it gets out of image range,and that occurs because putpixel doesn't work to apply the stop code. and by not working I don't mean seeing,the R value doesn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using your code and trying it out on an image, putpixel is working as expected. The change in the pixels is very hard to see and that may be why you believe that it isn't working. Believe me, it is working, you just can't see it.

However, there are two problems I see with your code:

## 1) 999 is not encodable

`999` can not be encoded in a single pixel. The maximum value for a pixel is `255` (The range is 0-255). You need to choose a different stop code/sequence. I recommend changing the stop code to `255`.

## 2) When decoding, `a` has never been defined

You need to get the length of the message by another means. I suggest doing this with a counter:

```
counter = 0
while something:
    counter += 1

# do something with count here
```

All in all, a working version of your code would look like:

```
e=input('file and location?  ')
img=Image.open(e)
pmap=img.load()
imy=img.height
imx=img.width
if int(input('1 for encoding, 2 for decoding   '))==1:
    a=input('Your message?   ')
    for i in range(len(a)):
        r , g , b= img.getpixel((i+10,imy//2))
        img.putpixel((i+10,imy//2),(ord(a[i]),g,b))
    r,g,b=img.getpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2))
    img.putpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2),(255,g,b)) #255 is the stop code in     decoding
else:
    r=u=0
    m=''
    message_length=0
    while r!=255:
        message_length+=1
        r , g , b=img.getpixel((10+u,imy//2))
        m+=chr(r)
        u+=1
    print(m[:message_length-1])
img.save(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is there, but it's just a few single pixels. If I calculate the difference between original and new image, you'll see it in the middle left, stored in test2.png. In order to enhance contrast I have "equalized" the image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps

img=Image.open("image.jpg")
pmap=img.load()
img2=img.copy()
imy=img.height
imx=img.width
if int(input('1 for encoding, 2 for decoding   '))==1:
    a=input('Your message?   ')
    for i in range(len(a)):
        r , g , b=img.getpixel((i+10,imy//2))
        img.putpixel((i+10,imy//2),(ord(a[i]),g,b))
    r,g,b=img.getpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2))
    img.putpixel((len(a)+10,imy//2),(999,g,b)) #999 is the stop code in     decoding
else:
    r=u=0
    m=''
    while r!=999:
        r , g , b=img.getpixel((10+u,imy//2))
        m+=chr(r)
        u+=1
    print(m[:len(a)-1])
img.save("test.png")
img3=ImageChops.difference(img, img2)
img3=ImageOps.equalize(img3)
img3.save("test2.png")
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: I'm not looking to change how the picture looks,I simply want to encode a message into it by changing the pixels' R into the matching character's ascii code so i can decode the message later.I might be getting your point wrong,so I'd be happy if you could explain more

Comment: My point is: Your program is working. The image you save is different from the original image. But if my text to encode is "test", you are only modifying 4 single pixels (len(a)=4), so you won't see the difference with your naked eye. This is why I have subtracted the original and the new image, so only the difference remains. And since the difference is low in value (ord(a[i]) is around 60), I have amplified the gray values by equalizing it.